# altering json value to be substring

Tags: json, regex, jq

I have a value in a json result set I would like to alter to be a substring value of the original

```
{
   "label": "web page check",
  "target": "http://www.example.com/random/page"
},
{
   "label": "web page check1 ",
  "target": "http://www.example1.com/random/page"
},
```

what I would like to do is return it as

```
{
  "label": "web page check",
  "target": "https://www.example.com"
},
{
   "label": "web page check",
  "target": "https://www.example1.com"
}
```

I have tried

```
jq  '.[].target=(match(^https:\/\/[0-9a-zA-z.]*|^http:\/\/[0-9a-zA-z.]*).string)'

jq -c '.[] | {label: .label, target: (.target |=match(^https:\/\/[0-9a-zA-z.]*|^http:\/\/[0-9a-zA-z.]*).string})'
```

Comment: It would appear that you did not intend to change one of the "label" values, and that the snippet of data that is shown is intended to be part of a JSON array.  Please fix and/or clarify.  Following the [mcve] guidelines helps avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: Also, the given title of the question conflicts with the requirement implied by the example, to change "http:" to "https:".  Please fix the title or the example as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `sub` (**requires jq 1.5**) can be any PCRE.

```
.[].target |= sub("(?<=com).*$"; "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `capture` is often easier than using `match`. In your case, the following would be sufficient to modify the "target" values assuming your input is an array of objects along the lines suggested by the snippet:

```
map(.target |= (capture("https?(?<s>://[^/]*)") | "https" + .s))
```

Equivalently:

```
map(.target |= sub( "https?(?<s>://[^/]*).*"; "https" + .s) )
```